# Argue that the impromper integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1-e^{-2x^2}}{x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \frac{1-e^{-2x^2}}{x^2}
$$
for $x \neq 0$. Then I have to show that the improper integral
$$
\int_0^\infty g(t)
$$
is convergent.

**My attempt**

As $e^{-2x^2} \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$
\frac{1-e^{-2x^2}}{x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
Thus as the limit 
$$
\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \int_1^b \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1
$$
exists it follows from the comparison criteria that the improper integral is convergent. Is this approach alright? I think it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As simple as that...Perhaps writing clearly that the function is positive, but all the rest is right.

Comment: You posted the same question 10 minutes ago. Please do not do this again.

Comment: It was a question from an Analysis Exam which I am studying for but it was not the exactly same question as the one I asked earlier?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use that $e^{-2x^2} \le 1$ to write that inequality but rather the fact that $e^{-2x^2} \ge 0$.
However, you do need the fact that $e^{-2x^2} \le 1$ to conclude that 
$$0 \le \dfrac{1-e^{-2x^2}}{x^2}.$$

With that in place, you may use the comparison test.

Also, you've shown that the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty g(x)dx$ exists. You also need to argue that the integral on $[0, 1]$ exists as well.
However, that follows simply because $g$ can be made continuous on $[0, 1]$ by appropriately defining it at $0$.